# Keras: model.fit function reading y_train as (classes, samples) instead of (samples,classes)

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning

I am running a DL model using keras with y_train (target labels) of shape (400,14) where 400 is the batch_size and 14 are the number of classes.

Keras is reading my input example by example as (400,1) instead of (1,14)

```
model.fit(x_train, [y_l1_train,y_l2_train,y_l3_train,y_l4_train,y_l5_train,y_l6_train,y_l7_train,y_l8_train], validation_data=(x_val, [y_l1_val,y_l2_val,y_l3_val,y_l4_val,y_l5_val,y_l6_val,y_l7_val,y_l8_val]), epochs=1, batch_size=50)

#shapes of my arrays
x_train : (400, 10, 50)
y_l1_train shape : (400, 14)
y_l1_train first element [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Error Message

```
You are passing a target array of shape (400, 1) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. `categorical_crossentropy` expects targets to be binary matrices (1s and 0s) of shape (samples, classes).
```

I have tried everything but can't understand my mistake. Please help.

Comment: Could you please paste your definition of model here(so one can quickly reproduce the error)?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple outputs, so its not clear what is the issue without model code.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I actually don't have the right to share the code. This is the paper that we are building on top of : https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.09445

Comment: Sorry but then we cannot help you.

Comment: You could at least provide the model output dimensions for all outputs, the loss functions for all outputs, and the shapes of all training labels (y_l[n]_train).